# how to find out which component of Vue is being rendered in browser easily?

Tags: vue.js, web

Table.vue contains Row.vue and Form.vue inside.

Wanted behavior:
Row of the table will say the component comes from Row.vue

I was right-clicking the Row and went on "View page source", "inspect" and explored, but I couldn't find the answer.

Any solutions?

Also it would be awesome if there's a tool that helps with what I explained above with visual like this: instead of margin, border and such. It would be like Table.vue, Row.vue, etc...

[image: This but instead of margin, border and such. It would be like Table.vue, Row.vue, etc...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but there is a browser-based tool that might help you with debugging. It is compatible with both v2 and v3 and can be installed on firefox or chromium-based browsers

https://devtools.vuejs.org/

[image]

use this icon to target the component

[image]

Comment: Pretty much this one indeed.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks! this was my question. This works. If I hover a mouse on items from Vue Developer Tools, it highlights the view on the webpage. But I find it wee bit difficult to find what I want when there are many items to click especially when I didn't write the code. Was hoping I could click the component directly from the webpage and tells me what component or button it is. Don't think Vue Developer Tools have the ability. Also, SOF doesn't let me upvote because I don't have 15 reputation :(

Comment: It does have it, it the top right corner, updated answer